# number of multiplications and additions

Tags: computational-complexity

I would like to count the number of multiplications and addition in Cholesky Decomposition. Assume that I have Hermitian positive definite matrix. First, I will calculate all the entries in the lower triangular matrix, L using the Cholesky method. Then, I can count the number of multiplications and additions (MADs) in L. Let say I got MADs for all the entries in L = K^3/3 + K^2/2 - 5K/6.

My question is, 
1. Should I count MADs for the entries in the Upper Triangular matrix as well? which means, I need to multiply the answer in L by 2 because the entries in U is just the complex conjugate of L?
2. Or, I just need to count MADs in L only?

Comment: You need to count the operations that you really perform.

Comment: do you mean only for the lower triangular part?

Comment: Sorry, I have to repeat: you count the operations you really perform.